# mapreduce job not contacting new namenode after failover

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, failover

I have enabled Namenode high availability with automatic failover in my cluster. As a validation step , i killed one namenode and got the other namenode to active state. After that I submitted hdfs dfs -ls / command and it ran successfully. But when I run a wordcount job its showing connection refused error pointing to the namenode service I just killed. How can I rectify this error?

Comment: what's your hadoop version? And how have you configured the same i.e. configs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i found the error. I didnt change the configuration of tez which caused the problem. Everything is working good now. :)